# Not able to add the reference System.Runtime.InteropServices

Tags: collections

I want to use CollectionsMarshal but I'm not able to add the name space CollectionsMarshal if I try to add it is throwing the error "CollectionsMarshal' does not exist in the current context" and i cant find the reference also.

I'm trying to use the CollectionsMarshal in visual studio 2022 for my wpf project, I need help to add the reference to CollectionsMarshal.